# filter wp_query result with custom field values

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I'm getting started with advanced custom fields. 
I have a category field (main_category) where the categories given below are selected using the radio buttons.

```
1. Electronics
2. Programming
3. Design
```

where there are sub categories for these categories. they are set using the conditional radio buttons for each category.
the sub categories are indexed, the fields are given ion brackets,

```
Post Type: article
Field Name: Category
Field key : main_category

1. Electronics - - - - - - - - (electronics)
        Linear Electronics - -      (elect_linear)
        Computer Networks- - -      (elect_networks)
        Microwave Engineering-      (elect_microwave)
        MicroProcessors- - - -      (elect_micropro)
2. Programming - - - - - - - - (programming)
        ObjectiveC - - - - - -      (prog_objc)
        Pythion  - - - - - - -      (prog_python)
        JavaScript - - - - - -      (prog_js)
        PHP  - - - - - - - - -      (prog_php)
3. Design     - - - - - -  - - (design)
        Illustrator  - - - - -      (desgn_ai)
        Photoshop   - - - - - -     (desgn_ps)
        After Effects   - - - -     (desgn_ae)
        Cinema 4d   - - - - - -     (desgn_cf)
```

the WP_Query was made,

```
$articles = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'article',
  'meta_key' => 'main_category',
);


$query_articles = new WP_Query( $articles);
```

it returned an array $query_articles which contains all the posts.,
how can I filter through the array $query_articles ? so that I would add 'tagged in php' for the articles in the php sub category.?

what i could do in my knowledge was to query arrays with different categories..

```
$electronics = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'article',
  'meta_key' => 'main_category',
  'meta_value' => 'electronics'
);
$programming = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'article',
  'meta_key' => 'main_category',
  'meta_value' => 'programming'
);
$design = array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type' => 'article',
  'meta_key' => 'main_category',
  'meta_value' => 'design'
);



//query variables
$query_electronics = new WP_Query( $electronics);
$query_programming = new WP_Query( $programming);
$query_design = new WP_Query( $design );
```

but the sub categories always messed up and also it eats up lots of resource.

ps. this is for a blog i'm developing in localhost.
thanks for any help and comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `main_category` is a category (custom taxonomy), then you're querying it wrong. This should go like this:

```
$electronics = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'main_category' => 'electronics'
);
$query_electronics = new WP_Query( $electronics );
```

If that's a custom field, use `meta_query`:

```
$electronics = array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'article',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'main_category',
        'value' => 'electronics'
    ),
);
$query_electronics = new WP_Query( $electronics );
```

Comment: by the way how it comes to echo something like tagged in '*some category*'?